# Новая библиотека dll вызывает ошибку в старом приложении

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Всем доброго времени суток! Получил проект visual studio, который судя по информации о версии в файле sln библиотеки, был написан в visual studio 2015. В проекте, библиотеку я пересобрал так же, как и приложение на студии 2019. У меня всё приложение работает корректно, но при передаче библиотеки проекта заказчику в момент обращения приложения к библиотеке возникает ошибка приложения. Попробовал установить версию готовой программы полученной у заказчика, получил сразу же вылет в момент запуска приложения. После установки пакета visual c++ 2008 приложение запускается на моём ПК, но при обращении к библиотеке оно вылетает как и у заказчика.
[image: первый скрин]
[image: второй скрин]
Есть ли возможность написать dll которая не вызывала бы сбоев независимо от того, в какой версии visual studio она была написана? Или же существует жёсткая взаимосвязь между тем, каким компилятором пользовались при сборке приложения и сборке dll?

Comment: Надо смотреть на API, которое предоставляет Ваша библиотека. Если там передаются хоть какие то плюсовые классы через границу, то нужно очень внимательно не только за версией компилятора следить, а и за опциями компиляции.

Comment: Если библиотека именно С++, то приложение и библиотека должны собираться строго одним и тем же компилятором, строго с совместимыми настройками. С другой стороны, не факт, что проблема на картинке вызвана какой-то несовместимостью, а не просто кривостью самой библиотеки или приложения.